# A $2$-Sylow of $A_6$ is self normalizing

Tags: group-theory, permutations, sylow-theory

Let $A_6$ be the alternating group of order $6$. Let $R$ be a $2$-Sylow of $A_6$, I want to show that $R=N_{A_6}(R)$.

---

What I have done is that we have that there is a monomorphism from $S_4$ to $A_6$ then there is a $2$-Sylow $Q$ of $S_4$ such that $Q\cong R$ and it can be shown that $Q=D_8$.

We also have the fact that $A_6$ has no elements of order $6$ and $10$.

Let $Z$ be the center of $R$, by the mentioned monomorphism we have that $Z\cong Z(Q)$, and we know that $|Z(Q)|=2$, so $|Z|=2$.

On the other hand, we have that $Z\; char\; R\triangleleft N_{A_6}(R)$, then $Z\triangleleft N_{A_6}(R)$, that means for all $g\in N_{A_6}(R)$, we have that $Z^g=Z$, but as $Z$ has order 2, and $g^{-1}1g=1$, therefore $1\neq a\in Z$, $a^g=a$, so $ag=ga$ for all $g\in N_{A_6}(R)$, then $Z\leq Z(N_{A_6}(R))$.

By Lagrange's theorem, we have that $2$ divides $|Z(N_{A_6}(R))|$ (and this is where I am stuck).

Comment: $N_G(P)=P$ means "self-normalizing", right? Here $G=A_6$ and $P$ is a $2$-Sylow subgroup. For $G=S_n$ see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131237/why-are-sylow-2-subgroups-of-s-n-self-normalizing). Do the same in your case.

Comment: I would go on like this. If $N(R)>R$, then the group $N(R)$ has an element of order $3$ or $5$. Since the center of $N(R)$ contains an element of order $2$, then $A_6$ has an element of order $6$ or $10$.

Comment: Actually, I found a nice proof for $A_7$ [here](http://at.yorku.ca/b/ask-an-algebraist/2008/3445.htm). Try to adapt it to $A_6$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you, but I am looking for a proof that uses some of the facts I mention.

Comment: @kabenyuk Thanks that is the answer I was looking for.