# Do normalizers of $p$-subgroups of $S_n$ always grow?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Recently I encountered, the 'normalizers grow principle' which gives an equivalent characterization of Nilpotent groups.
Looking at the other 'extreme' case of $S_n$, my question is:

> Let $n \geq 4$. Is it true that $N_{S_n}(P) \supsetneq P$ for any Sylow subgroup $P$ of $S_n?$

I have been unable to prove this but this is true in $S_4$. It is easy to show that this is true for $n=p$.

It is  true that $S_n$ has non-trivial self-normalizing (for which normalizer doesn't grow) subgroups.

Also it is true that  for any group $G$ normalizers of $p$-subgroups which are not Sylow always grow.(This can be shown by the above principle, for example).

Comment: If $G$ is a finite group, and $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, then $N_G(N_G(P)) = N_G(P)$. Since no Sylow of $S_n$ is normal for $n\geq 4$, the answer is no, never grow more than once.

Comment: adding to Arturo's comment: A Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_n$ is self-normalizing if and only if $p=2$.

Comment: I would suggest that you phrase your questions more formally so that it clear what you are asking. I think you are asking whether, for Sylow $p$-subgroups $P$ of $S_n$ with $n>3$, $P$ is always strictly contained in $N_{S_n}(P)$. Brauer Suzuki has answered that question.

Comment: @DerekHolt Apologies. I have now edited the question. I used normalizers grow in the sense it is used in the 'normalizers grow principle'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true if you assume $p > 2$. Here is a sketch for the proof.

A $p$-Sylow of $S_n$ can be constructed as a wreath product $P = C_p \wr \cdots \wr C_p$ of cyclic groups of order $p$. Here the number $C_p$ involved is $k$, where $p^k$ is the largest power of $p$ with $p^k \leq n$.

Consider a wreath product $X \wr Y \leq S_{ab}$ with $X \leq S_a$, $Y \leq S_b$. If $Y \trianglelefteq Z$, then $X \wr Y \trianglelefteq X \wr Z$.

Thus because $C_p$ is not self-normalizing in $S_p$ for $p > 2$, conclude that a $p$-Sylow of $S_n$ is not self-normalizing for $p > 2$.

In the case where $p = 2$, you can prove that a $2$-Sylow of $S_n$ is self-normalizing. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131237/why-are-sylow-2-subgroups-of-s-n-self-normalizing).

The idea is that you can first show that the normalizer of $P = (C_2 \wr \cdots \wr C_2) \wr C_2$ must normalize the base of the wreath product. Then $N_G(P) = X \wr C_2$ for some $X$ normalizing $(C_2 \wr \cdots \wr C_2)$, so by induction $N_G(P) = P$.

Comment: Your description of the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $S_n$ is incomplete. You are describing a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_{p^k}$. In general it is a direct product of wreath products of this type determined by the base $p$ expansion of $n$. For example a Sylow $3$-subgorup of $S_{42}$ is $(C_3 \wr C_3 \wr C_3) \times (C_3 \wr C_3) \times C_3^2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Yes you are right, what I wrote is not correct. For $n \neq p^k$ basically the same argument works - I can edit this later.

Comment: @spin Thank you! I have never come accross wreath product..i will read up...seems like a useful construct especially when dealing with normal subgroups